# Create a 'BufferedReader' out of a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm fairly new to Java, and I need to create a 'BufferedReader' for a JTextField. What needs to happen is, when the program calls my `getText()` method, It needs to wait until it recieves input from the Enter key event handler. If i do something like:

```
String input = null;
while(true) {
  if(!input.equals(null)) {
    break;
  }
}
```

I get nullpointerexception errors. I've thought about it, and determined that since `getText()` has to return data to the method that called it, I would have to run like a nested method inside the `getText()` method, that would be able to run the code to run the data. Any ideas?

Comment: Change your code to `if(input != null)` to avoid the `NullPointerException` you're getting. Otherwise you're calling `.equals()` on a string that was just initialized to `null`, hence the exception.

Comment: If you need to wait and get data from a user then use a JOptionPane. See the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is not how Swing (or just about any UI framework) works.  Start by taking a look at [Concurrecy in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for reasons why you should NEVER block the Event Dispatching Thread...

Swing is an event driven environment.  The user clicks the mouse, and event is raised.  The user presses a key, and event is raised.

Rather then using loops or polling, Swing utilises "listeners", which is a form of the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html).

This allows you to attach a callback interface to an object and it will tell you when something has occured.

Take a look at [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) for more examples.

If you need to know when the user has pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you should attach a `ActionListener` to the `JTextField`.  It will trigger an `actionPerformed` event when ever the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>

See [How to write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

because, input is null.

```
String input = null;
if(!input.equals(null))
```

`"null"` means "It haven't initialized, or it has no value".
The equals method (and every other method) requires input to not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Can't call a method on a null object. Check if input is null.

```
if(input != null)
```